# What's the best way to insert a user reference field value into the database?

Tags: nodes, users

I use the references module. I have a custom form, into which I capture names into a user reference field via the autocomplete widget. So, on the form, if a user types Joe, the following appears in the input box:

```
Joe [uid: 5]
```

Now, I do not want to insert this into my database as it is because my 'Name' field is expecting just the uid. So I need to pass '5' to the database, not the string `Joe [uid: 5]`.

To accomplish this, before I write my record to the database I pass the string `Joe [uid: 5]` through this code:

```
// * Search for match (integer) to regular expression and put in $integer.
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $form_state['values']['name'], $integer);

// * Return string representation of array elements.
$name_uid = implode(' ', $integer[0]);
```

`$name_uid` now contains '5' and is ready to be inserted. Is there an existing function that already does this? or does anyone have a better way?

The downside of my method is that you cannot have numbers in names, like 'Joe 2'. I've looked in user_reference.module, but it's not obvious, to me, how they do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `user_reference_autocomplete_value()` and `user_reference_autocomplete_validate()`, that's how the user_reference module does it

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make `user_reference_autocomplete_validate()` work for me so I turned my own code into a function, which now solves my numbers in names problem. I can't see why it would ever fail, but if anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

```
/**
 * Search for regular expression matches and return the last match.
 */

function extract_id($subject) {
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $subject, $matches);
    return end($matches[0]);
}
```